# I am trying to import ms-access data into SQL Server but I am getting an error saying that column names must be unique. How can I resolve this?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012

I am trying to import data from an .accdb access file but cannot import it because at least two tables have the same column name. Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nqGw.png) of the error.

Comment: Many many tables are 100% free to have the same column names. It sounds like you are importing a query and NOT a table. I mean, it RATHER common to say have 10 tables each with say address fields and say each with a city field. That never been a issue nor problem. So, if you limiting this importing to tables and not Access queries, then you should not be having any problems. Possible that some column name in one of the Access tables badly formed - or a column name that includes what looks like a table qualifier, and thus is messing up the import. Same name columns from different tables is fine

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I am getting an [error](https://i.imgur.com/JH6V5rA.png)

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal it turns out that the issue was caused by importing queries. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Rename one of the fields, or import to two or more tables in SQL Server.

Or import via a query where you use an alias for one of the dupe fields.